# Catkin: How to find auto-generated roslisp messages?

Tags: ros, catkin, message-generation, ros-package-path, roslisp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently migrating to using roslisp under groovy. For compiling bigger projects I use roslisp_repl with slime (a.k.a. "the REPL"). I have the problem that the REPL does not find auto-generated roslisp messages from wet packages **within** my catkin workspace.

I did some digging into the code behind the REPL and learned that for compilation it searches all subdirectories of the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and the ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES for valid lisp-system (valid lisp-system are directories containing an asd-file).

My problem description:

- catkin workspace at ~/ros/groovy/catkin_ws
- .bashrc sources /opt/ros/groovy/source.bash and ~/ros/groovy/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
- wet package test_msgs in src-workspace with some message defintions
- catkin_make successfully builds messages and puts generated roslisp messages in ~/ros/groovy/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp/ros/test_msgs.
- ROS_PACKAGE_PATH does not contain this path
- ROSLISP_PACKAGE_PATH is not set
- as a result the REPL complains that it cannot find the generated lisp-code

Here are my questions:

- Has ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES been intentionally deprecated in groovy?
- If no, could it be used to contain /opt/ros/groovy/share/common-lisp/ros and all /devel/share/common-lisp/ros sub-directories of all overlays?
- If yes, how can lisp-compilers find the generated lisp-code in the devel-section of my overlay?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65388/catkin:-how-to-find-auto-generated-roslisp-messages?/) by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/2542/georg-bartels/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2013-06-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-06-18**:
You do not have to source two setup.bash files. The second one will effectively override everything from the first. So sourcing the file from your custom workspace is enough.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-06-18**:
Regarding the fact that the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH does not contain the path: after compiling your workspace you have to source the setup.bash file from the subfolder devel. Than ~/ros/groovy/catkin_ws/devel should be part of tour ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

**Comment by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/2542/georg-bartels/) on 2013-06-18**:
@Dirk: Thanks for clarifying that I need to source only one setup.bash-file. Regarding the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH: I just re-did the first catkin tutorial from ros.org (creating workspace). After sourcing devel/setup.bash after catkin_make ~/catkin_ws/devel is not part of the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH for me.

**Comment by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/2542/georg-bartels/) on 2013-06-18**:
@Dirk: With regards to ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES, is this environment variable deprecated or can we use it to point to both /opt/ros//share/common-lisp/ros and ~//devel/share/common-lisp/ros?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-06-18**:
The `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is set by `roslib` so if that is not in your underlay or in your workspace it will not be set: https://github.com/ros/ros/blob/groovy-devel/core/roslib/env-hooks/10.ros.sh.em#L33

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-06-18**:
My previous comment was incorrect, the RPP only lists the source space - never devel. I don't know how ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES is used and why at all. I have never used (ros)lisp. We should talk about that offline (via Google hangout/something else) to figure out how roslisp is supposed to work.

**Comment by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/2542/georg-bartels/) on 2013-06-18**:
@Dirk: Sure. I'll send you message with my gmail-account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dirk has solved the issue by submitting a patch to roslisp:

https://github.com/ros/roslisp/commit/a050701edde477fb06a807b9e097108730deeb06

Basically, the environment hook of roslisp was broken under groovy. As of roslisp version 1.9.13 the environment variable `$ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES` is back and points to all devel/share/common-lisp sub-directories of all catkin workspaces. This makes sure that the roslisp buildsystem called ASDF can find the autogenerated roslisp messages from wet source packages: ASDF recursively crawls all sub-directories of `$ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES` and `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` for lisp system definitions, e.g. files with extention *.asd.

---

Originally posted by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/2542/georg-bartels/) with karma: 157 on 2013-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0